# Using Migrate API to select items from within an Events JSON array

Tags: migrations, 8

I am using the migration import to pull in events from a calendar service json api. I can capture and map almost all the event details except the start date which is contained within an array. I tried to use the extract plugin but can't quite get it to work.

```
"events": [
   {
      "event": {
         "id": 920693,
         "title": "This is the event",
         "url": "http://woodowloriginaldesigns.com/what-lies-beneath/",
         "photo_id": 481020,
         "detail_views": 892,
         "event_instances": [
             {
                 "event_instance": {
                     "id": 2711527,
                     "ranking": 0,
                     "event_id": 920693,
                     "start": "2017-06-28T00:00:00-04:00",
                     "end": null,
                     "all_day": true
                 }
            }
    ],
    "address": "124 Main Street USA",
    }
  }
```

I am trying to get the `"start"` date out of there. The process section for my yaml file for the start date currently looks like this:

```
field_importdate:
  plugin: extract
  source: event_instances
  index: 
    - 0 
    - event_instance
    - start
```

When I omit this, I can successfully pull in/map all the other fields with a `drush migrate-import jobnamehere`  command.

- How should my extract plugin be configured here to get the start
  date?

Happy to provide more details and entirety of yaml file if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mapping directly rather than using extract?

```
field_importdate: event_instances/0/event_instance/start
```

Comment: I have tried that with no success unfortunately.